# How to mock async function using jest framework?

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

i tried to mock the async function that is making call to service and process and resolve promise for the async function. so in below code its not mocking for some reason , any idea what i have implemented incorrect ?

Any example how to mock async function with below code will be highly appreciated.

main.ts

```
export async function getMemberInfoCache(tokenID: string): Promise < IInfoObj[] > {
    if (!tokenID) {
        throw new Error("tokenID needed for getMemberInfoCache");
    }
    const cacheObj: IGetCacheRequest = {
        key: tokenID,
        cachetype: "memberInfoCache"
    };
    const memberInfo = await CacheController.getInstance().getDetailsWrapper(cacheObj);

    const specialtyMemberObjs: any = [];
    const cacheArray: IspecialtyMemberInfo = memberInfo.cacheobject.specialtyMemberInfo;
        memberObj.lastName = member.memberInfo.lastName;
        memberObj.dateOfBirth = member.memberInfo.dateOfBirth;

        specialtyMemberObjs.push(memberObj);
    });

    return specialtyMemberObjs;
}
```

main.spec.ts

```
import {
    getMemberInfoCache
} from "./main.ts"
jest.mock(. / main.ts)

describe("Testing afterSpread passMakeResponse", () => {
    let callCacheFunction;
    beforeEach(async () => {
        callCacheFunction = await getMemberInfoCache.mockImplementation(() => {
            Promise.resolve([{
                key: value
            }]);
        });

    });
    it('should call afterSpread', function() {
        expect(callCacheFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 16):

Aysnc functions are just functions that return a promise. You simply need to mock the function as you have done using `jest.mock` and then provide a mock return value. Here is one way to write a test against the `getMemberInfoCache` function.

```
describe("Testing afterSpread passMakeResponse", async () => {
    it('should call afterSpread', function() {
      getMemberInfoCache.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve([{
        key: value
      }]);

      await getMemberInfoCache();

      expect(callCacheFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});
```

One thing to note is that `jest.mock` will stub `getMemberInfoCache` for you so whenever you call `getMemberInfoCache` in your test file it will be calling the stubbed version.

Comment: ok thankss for the help , do we need to pass expected param to stubbed version or not ? like in my function its expecting a token to be passed

Comment: Depends on your test. If you simply want to stub the method and return an expected value then you do not. But if you want to do something with the args and use a mockImplementation then you can do that as well. I typically do the former and just verify the args the method was called with.

Comment: solution is not working its  not taking await keyword i have async() as cb

Comment: ` describe("Testing afterSpread passMakeResponse", () => {
    it('should call afterSpread', async () =>{
        callFunction = getSpecialtyMemberInfoCache.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(finalResponse);

        await getSpecialtyMemberInfoCache();

        expect(callFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });

});` made it worked it passed the test but on my coverage it does not impacted looks its still not calling